# IIS - PHP - Problems to get POST and GET with IIS redirection

Tags: redirect, iis, get, http-status-code-404

I have a little problem with my php website in IIS, i custom the settings of IIS to do personal redirection with my class router.php (i don't use framework). Every 404 request redirect to index.php so i add this rule on my IIS config

I just have a probleme with the $_GET, the fist param of the get take the url of my website when the url path is like https://192.168.56.112/login, i think it's due to the redirect rule,

```
URL :  https://192.168.56.112/login?test=test&test1=test1
Reponse array(2) { ["404;https://192_168_56_112:443/login?test"]=> string(4) "test" ["test1"]=> string(5) "test1" }
```

As for $_POST it doesn't work if i don't send my request to the index.php

Thanks for your help

Comment: What problem did you have and what expectation do you want to get?

Comment: not an PHP related problem, please remove the tag..

Comment: Basically i want to get the $_POST in my /login page. But this page doesn't exist so i write a IIS rule for redirect every request on my index.php for after redirect to specific php file. And i think IIS can't give me $_POST of https://192.168.10.49/login because it execute a 404 redirection

Comment: And for the $_GET when i'm on a page which not exist, the $_get get also the url on the first parameter i don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my problems I just use

```
$this->body = $this->fixPOST(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

instead of

```
$_POST
```

And for the `$_GET` I removed the url in the first parameter.